# How to insert Grand Total column and row into datagridview with dynamic pivot c# winform

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview on my form which I use to pivot information from my database. Here is my query command to do so:

```
DECLARE @Date AS VARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS VARCHAR(MAX)
        
SELECT 
    @dATE = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CREATED, 101), '-', '/')) 
                   FROM repair_data_entry
                   WHERE MONTH(CREATED) = 12
                     AND YEAR(CREATED) = 2020
                   GROUP BY CREATED
                   ORDER BY CREATED
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = 'SELECT NAME AS TECH, ' + @Date + ' 
              FROM  
                  (SELECT NAME, CREATED, REP  
                   FROM repair_data_entry) AS S  
              PIVOT  
                  (COUNT(REP)  
                      FOR CREATED IN ('+@Date+')  
                  ) P'
EXECUTE(@query)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/70fbb5/15)

Here is my query to try and get the grand total column and row:

```
DECLARE @Date1 VARCHAR(MAX),
        @Date2 VARCHAR(MAX),
        @GrandTotalCol VARCHAR(MAX),
        @GrandTotalRow VARCHAR(MAX),
        @FinalQuery VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Date1 = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CREATED, 101), '-', '/')) 
                       FROM repair_data_entry
                       WHERE MONTH(CREATED) = 12
                         AND YEAR(CREATED) = 2020
                       GROUP BY CREATED
                       ORDER BY CREATED
                       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
        
SELECT @Date2  = COALESCE (@Date2 + ',[' + @Date1 + ']', '[' + @Date1 + ']')
FROM repair_data_entry 
GROUP BY CREATED
ORDER BY CREATED

SELECT @GrandTotalCol = COALESCE (@GrandTotalCol + 'ISNULL ([' + 
CAST (@Date1 AS VARCHAR) +'],0) + ', 'ISNULL([' + CAST(@Date1 AS VARCHAR)+ '],0) + ')
FROM repair_data_entry
GROUP BY CREATED
ORDER BY CREATED

SET @GrandTotalCol = LEFT (@GrandTotalCol, LEN (@GrandTotalCol)-1)
 
SELECT @GrandTotalRow = COALESCE(@GrandTotalRow + ',ISNULL(SUM([' + 
CAST(@Date1 AS VARCHAR)+']),0)', 'ISNULL(SUM([' + CAST(@Date1 AS VARCHAR)+']),0)')
FROM repair_data_entry
GROUP BY CREATED
ORDER BY CREATED
  
SET @FinalQuery = 'SELECT *, (' + @GrandTotalCol + ') 
AS [Grand Total] INTO  #temp
            FROM
                (SELECT NAME,CREATED,REP
                    FROM  repair_data_entry
                ) A
            PIVOT
                (
                 COUNT(REP)
                 FOR CREATED
                 IN ('  + @date1 +  ')
                ) B
ORDER BY NAME

SELECT * FROM  #temp_MatchesTotal 
UNION ALL
SELECT ''Grand Total'','''',' + @GrandTotalRow + ',  
ISNULL (SUM([Grand Total]),0) FROM  #temp

DROP TABLE  #temp'

EXECUTE(@FinalQuery)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c74ec/43)

I keep getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'

I'm not sure what do to but I know there's a way. This is my last resort of searching and searching and trying different things.

Here's my C# code:

```
DateTime month = DateTime.Today;
DateTime year = DateTime.Today;

using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"connection"))
{
    cn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmdDashboard = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmdDashboard.CommandText = "DECLARE @Date AS VARCHAR(MAX), @query AS VARCHAR(MAX) select @Date = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATE, 101), '-', '/')) FROM repair_data_entry WHERE MONTH(DATE) = '" + month.Month + "' AND YEAR(DATE) = '" + year.Year + "' GROUP BY DATE ORDER BY DATE FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') set @query = 'SELECT NAME AS TECH, ' + @Date + ' FROM (SELECT NAME, DATE, REPAIR FROM repair_data_entry) AS S PIVOT (COUNT(REPAIR) FOR DATE IN('+@Date+')) P' EXECUTE(@query)";

        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdDashboard);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        cmdDashboard.Connection = cn;

        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "repair_data_entry");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "repair_data_entry";

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Frozen = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Frozen = true;

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        }

        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

Some things are different from the fiddle like the date column and the month and year.

I'm not sure if that's even the correct way to do this. I'm still learning C# and SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok based on your query , here is what you need to do :

> ```
> DECLARE @Datecolumns VARCHAR(MAX),
>         @GrandTotalCol VARCHAR(MAX),
>         @FinalQuery VARCHAR(MAX)
>
> SELECT @Datecolumns = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CREATED, 101), '-', '/')) 
>                        FROM repair_data_entry
>                        GROUP BY CREATED
>                        ORDER BY CREATED
>                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
>
> set @GrandTotalCol =  @Datecolumns + ',[GrandTotal]'
>
> SET @FinalQuery = 'SELECT *
> INTO  #temp
> FROM
> (
> select 
>   Name
>   ,case when GROUPING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CREATED, 101)) = 1 
>       then ''GrandTotal'' 
>       else CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CREATED, 101) end as CREATED
>   , COUNT(REP) REP
> from repair_data_entry
> group by name , ROLLUP (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CREATED, 101))
> ) as source 
>             PIVOT
>                 (
>                  SUM(REP)
>                  FOR CREATED
>                  IN ('  + @GrandTotalCol +  ')
>                 ) B
> ORDER BY NAME
>
> SELECT * FROM  #temp
>
> DROP TABLE  #temp'
>
> EXECUTE(@FinalQuery) 
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Name  | 11/02/2020 | 12/01/2020 | 12/02/2020 | GrandTotal
> :---- | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------:
> BILL  |       null |          6 |          5 |         11
> BILL2 |          1 |          3 |          3 |          7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4b9512b055e164e0282e573b1f4e5b13)*

Comment: I'm using sql server 2014. How I want it to look is like an excel pivot with a grand total column and grand total row. This work perfectly though! Thank You! I understand it and I can see what it's doing. When I try to add the grand total row, I get the row as a column. [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=64cd374b74b1667fc0cee7d26e330306).
Here's how I'm trying to get it:[image](https://imgur.com/a/1VFpodw)

Answer (score 0):

these two lines below don't look correct at all, specially when you are trying to prepare @GrandTotalRow with sum() function

```
SELECT @GrandTotalCol = COALESCE (@GrandTotalCol + 'ISNULL ([' + 
CAST (@Date1 AS VARCHAR) +'],0) + ', 'ISNULL([' + CAST(@Date1 AS VARCHAR)+ '],0) + ')
FROM repair_data_entry
GROUP BY CREATED
ORDER BY CREATED

SET @GrandTotalCol = LEFT (@GrandTotalCol, LEN (@GrandTotalCol)-1)
 
SELECT @GrandTotalRow = COALESCE(@GrandTotalRow + ',ISNULL(SUM([' + 
CAST(@Date1 AS VARCHAR)+']),0)', 'ISNULL(SUM([' + CAST(@Date1 AS VARCHAR)+']),0)')
FROM repair_data_entry
GROUP BY CREATED
ORDER BY CREATED
```

here is output print @GrandTotalCol:

```
ISNULL([[12/01/2020],[12/02/2020]],0) + ISNULL ([[12/01/2020],[12/02/2020]],0) +
```

and  print @GrandTotalRow:

```
ISNULL(SUM([[12/01/2020],[12/02/2020]]),0),ISNULL(SUM([[12/01/2020],[12/02/2020]]),0)
```

none of them are producing valid sql syntax:

- ISNULL( only takes 2 arguments
- SUM() takes only 1 arguments
- unbalanced [[ and ]]

instead I suggest you study more about `GROUP BY ROLLUP` command , It might be helpful for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't know who marked your explanation as not useful. I found it useful as I'm still learning all of this. Thanks for the point in the right direction!

Still looking for a concrete direction though.

Comment: @Bill you are welcome , paste your desired output , so we could help you better, you can vote this up if it was helpful , thanks

Comment: @Bill also which version of sql are you using?